# Creating persistent, durable "worker box" Docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am looking for a way to build a Docker container that:

- is a modern Ubuntu Server (21.04 or thereabouts); **and**
- instead of being an ephemeral container like Docker is typically used for, I will actually use this as a sort of "*persistent, working linux box*" where I will install all sorts of tools (homebrew, git, node, etc.) and will shut it down and fire it up many times, and I *need* those tools and my whole file system to persist across runs

My best attempt at a `docker-compose.yml` thus far:

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
  workbox:
    image: ubuntu
    container_name: workbox
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ???:???

volumes:
  ???:
```

For one, I'm not sure if `ubuntu` is the right image to be specifyin here for Ubuntu Server 21.04, but that's the best I could find.

The main issue here is I'm not sure how to mount-bind the volumes between my host and this `workbox` container. There's a directory on my host (Mac laptop) located at `~/workspace/workbox` and ideally I'd like to use that as a parent directory for *everything* on my `workbox` filesystem. **Is this possible?**

This may be putting the cart before the horse here, because at the end of the day, I just need an Ubuntu Server container that I can:

1. start up
2. ssh in
3. download a bunch of tools (git, node, brew, etc.) and create my own files on the container's file system
4. exit ssh
5. shut the container down
6. walk away for hours, days, weeks, millenia
7. come back
8. start the container back up and -- voila! -- everything is still there

How can I achieve this?

Comment: That setup sounds like you're looking for a virtual-machine setup (maybe based on VirtualBox) and a tool to configure its environment (maybe Vagrant).  In particular a VM setup running a stock Linux distribution would support "ssh in" and "everything is still there" with no special effort, but a Docker-based setup would require lots of customization.

Comment: Yep thanks but I am not looking for "outside the box" (no pun intended!) solutionizing, and there is a specific reason why I can't use traditional VMs, VirtualBox, Vagrant, etc. I specifically need Docker to do this for me, even if it means having to do something zany like: (1) bind-mount a volume for all my created files and (2) run a script to reinstall git, node, etc. every time the container starts up, etc.

Comment: You should avoid mounting system directories, which is where your tools will be installed. Install tools as part of your `Dockerfile`, and mount one or more data folders for your files.

Answer (score 0):

I tried testing some scenarios myself and binding some folder to the rootfs but this isn't allowed. But, if its just a basic "tooling machine" you could run an ubuntu container in interactive mode with tty connected, Ctrl + D when you're finished, and when you need it again just run  `docker ps -a` search for the container name and start it again in interactive mode.
as long as you don't delete volumes on your machine (like with `docker system prune` which will try to clean your host of docker object and data like images, volumes containers, and what else) there's no reason why you can't just exit the container when you're done and start it when you need it again.
just to make life simpler here's an example working day using it:

always better to specify image version to minor to avoid sudden changes
`docker run -it --name testing_container ubuntu:21.04 bash`

do your work like installing packages, using Linux commands that you need, and when you're done Ctrl + D to exit the container.

one millennia passes and you need that container again (because we overridden the container startup command  its saved to it so no need to specify bash or any other shell you prefer again):

`docker start -i testing_container`

Another even nicer solution to bind a folder from your personal rig (/personal_files) to the container and while using the container place files you want to access later from the docker host in that folder. An example command:

`docker run -it --name testing_container -v "/c/Users/username/ubuntu_files:/personal_files" ubuntu:21.04 bash`